# What are the differences between XPath and JXPath?

Tags: xpath, jxpath

I need to get the values from a DOM object using Java, I would like to know the differences between XPath & JXPath.

Answer (score 2):

XPath is a W3C-defined language for finding data within XML documents. There are many implementations. The latest version is XPath 3.1, but many implementations only support the original version 1.0.

JXPath is an open-source library that implements (some version of?) the XPath language, applying it specifically to navigation of an XML view of a general graph of Java objects, rather than an XML document per se.